# Word VBA: How to reference a chart in a table

Tags: vba, charts, ms-word

In a Word document, I have several tables into which I have placed charts within cells. Now I need to access these charts through VBA, to update data values and other properties. The logic driving the updates to the charts is linked to the table the charts are embedded in, so I need to know something about the table context when accessing the charts.

Originally, I had planned to bookmark the tables, and then iterate through the charts associated with each table. However, I now realise that the Word "Table" object doesn't have a "Shapes", or "Inlineshapes", or "Charts" collection.

So my question is: what is the best way to access/reference charts embedded in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just realised that each cell's "Range" property has an "Inlineshapes" collection where charts embedded will appear.

So I can do this:

```
With Word.Application

    .Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="BookmarkName"

    Dim wTable As Word.Table
    Set wTable = .Selection.Tables(1)

    Dim wChart As Word.chart
    Set wChart = wTable.Cell(3, 4).Range.InlineShapes(1).chart
End With
```

But this means iterating around the cells in the table to get to the charts. 
However, maybe there's a better way...!

Comment: Not sure if it is going to make any difference to how you are doing things, but the key here is that it's the Range that contains the InlineShape objects. So for a given Table, you don't have to iterate through the Cells to get the Charts, you can iterate through (say) ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.InlineShapes